# How can I run a list of independent IO actions in parallel?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

Is there something that does the same thing as `sequenceA` does to `[IO a]`, but that runs them concurrently? I don’t need any fancy concurrency stuff like locking since all IO actions are independent.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel

Comment: `mapCuncurrently` in `async` package? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:mapConcurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async` package works well for this.  As mentioned in a comment, `mapConcurrently` from that package will run a list of IO actions in parallel.  In particular, specialized to a list, the expression `mapConcurrently id` has the type you want:

```
mapConcurrently id :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
```

so:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main = mapConcurrently id [putStrLn "foo", putStrLn "bar"]
```

If you don't care about the return values, use `mapConcurrently_ id` instead.

If you don't actually need IO and are really tring to run a bunch of pure computations in parallel, then the `parallel` package would be more appropriate.